# Detecting if Leaflet Map is in Full Screen mode or not

Tags: jquery, leaflet

Does anyone know how to detect if a leaflet map is set to fullscreen? So [here](http://www.archturia.com/vis/) is an example I am playing with. I want to be able to detect if the user is in the fullscreen state.
I have tried this:

```
$(".leaflet-control-zoom-fullscreen").click(function(e){
  console.log(e);
  if(e.clientX <=20){
    $("#dashboardA").show();
  }else if(e.clientX > 150){
    $("#dashboardA").hide();
  }else{
    $("#dashboardA").show();
  }
});
```

The above code sort of works.But i get the feeling there is a better way to do this. 
For example, let's say I am displaying something on the map and want to hide/show it when the user moves between fullscreen and normal mode. How would i do this effectively?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [Leaflet.fullscreen](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen#api) plugin instead, you can call `map.isFullscreen()` to get the map's fullscreen status.

Comment: Real quick, does this require the usage of map box? If so, then this will not work for me. But it is a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: No, it doesn't require you to use Mapbox. What gives you that impression?

Comment: I was seeing the inclusion of mapbox js code, so i was just checking before i unwind my logic. Looks like you solved it. If you thought this question was relevant, kindly give it the old thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

documentation says

```
map.on('fullscreenchange', function () {
    if (map.isFullscreen()) {
        console.log('entered fullscreen');
    } else {
        console.log('exited fullscreen');
    }
});
```

if doesnt work use this instead

```
map.on('enterFullscreen', function(){
});

map.on('exitFullscreen', function(){
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I tried 'fullscreenchange', 'enterFullscreen', and 'enterFullScreen'.