# How to detect when Mapbox/Leaflet enters or exits fullscreen mode

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How can I detect when Mapbox or Leaflet enters or exits fullscreen mode?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36459686/1253298) where someone said this:

> Documentation says:
>
> ```
> map.on('fullscreenchange', function () {
>     if (map.isFullscreen()) {
>         console.log('entered fullscreen');
>     } else {
>         console.log('exited fullscreen');
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> If doesnt work, use this instead:
>
> ```
> map.on('enterFullscreen', function(){
> });
>
> map.on('exitFullscreen', function(){
> });
> ```

I tried that, as well as a few variations of the event type parameter. No dice.

Also, [the documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-event) doesn't mention an event for this.

Note that I am using Mapbox GL JS.

Comment: Comparing Mapbox GL JS and Leaflet is like comparing apples with oranges. They are completely different projects, with different code bases and different APIs. If you're using Mapbox GL JS see it's API doc at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#fullscreencontrol. As it stands there isn't any events fired by the FullscreenControl. What's the use case?

Comment: I need to trigger Angular 2+ change detection when exiting from fullscreen.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a late response but to anyone in the future this is how I approached it (for mapbox GL JS (without leaflet).

```
map.on("resize", () => {
    if (document.fullscreenElement) // do something
});
```

You can give the map wrapper div a name and exclusively also check if the map is what triggered the fullscreen event

```
map.on("resize", () => {
    if (document.fullscreenElement?.attributes.name.value === "mapWrapper") // do something
});
```

And if you are using React you can use a state to hold this information.

```
const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = useState();
...
map.on("resize", () => {
  setIsFullScreen(
    document.fullscreenElement?.attributes.name.value === "mapWrapper"
  );
});
...
if (isFullScreen) //do something
```

Comment: No it won’t. I’ve tested it. I’m clearly checking for document.fullScreenElement

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really simple. You don't need anything from Leaflet or Mapbox. Just use an event listener on the document object.

```
let fullScreenChange;  

if ('onfullscreenchange' in window.document) {
  fullScreenChange = 'fullscreenchange';
} else if ('onmozfullscreenchange' in window.document) {
  fullScreenChange = 'mozfullscreenchange';
} else if ('onwebkitfullscreenchange' in window.document) {
  fullScreenChange = 'webkitfullscreenchange';
} else if ('onmsfullscreenchange' in window.document) {
  fullScreenChange = 'MSFullscreenChange';
}

function onFullscreenChange() {
   // Your stuff.
}

window.document.addEventListener(fullScreenChange, onFullscreenChange);
```